# Send a Notification to a Wordpress Theme

Tags: plugins, notifications

I'm basically looking for something or at least a base line to create a piece of code that allow me to send notifications to my clients via the Wordpress CMS.

The Study case is basically like, I'm creating some themes and clients can select between different "modules" to buy, so I'm looking for a way to notify when new modules are available, or when I update some of them.

I've been looking for a solution around and I cannot find anything good enough, would be great.

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [dashboard widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dashboard_Widgets_API) that grabs a feed.